# Multiligual Support in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, internationalization, multilingual, collation

I'm looking to find if it's possible to store characters from multiple languages with widely varying character set (e.g. Latin and Japanese alphabet) into a `VARCHAR` column in SQL Server 2008/12 DB. I read about the concept of collations in sql server. I cannot change the data type to `NVARCHAR`. Is there a code page that mimics the Unicode character set ? Is it correct to say that data in a column of the type `VARCHAR` would be encoded as per the code page specified in the collation ? In addition, how does the system maps characters from one code page to other ?

Comment: as already mentioned,  I cannot change the data type to NVARCHAR

Comment: *why* can't you use nvarchar?

Comment: @podiluska  Would require changing the table structure of too many tables. I don't think my manager would let me do that.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `nvarchar` datatype to store characters that occupy more than one byte (yes, I know that you've said that you can't change it, just talking about the options).

If one byte is enough, I'd recommend using different column with appropriate collation for each language. Collations affect not only comparation and sorting, but also a way the information is stored and possibly transformed (which is not a good thing when it happens).

If you don't need localized sorting capabilities, use `binary` collation.

There is also a sample on MSDN on using UTF-8 UDT:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877964%28v=sql.110%29.aspx